# Serial Port (RS -232) Connection in C++

Tags: c++, serial-port, mingw

I have done serial port RS-232 connection in C++ using 16-bit compiler (I was using Turbo C++ IDE). It included header file `bios.h` which contain all the required functions for reading values from the port. Now I want to read value from serial port using C++ 32-bit Mingw compiler. I am using Dev CPP as my IDE. Here I could not find `bios.h`. Are there any special header files available for this purpose in Mingw? I am using 32-bit compiler now because in my college project I got to use Exception handling which I guess is not supported in Turbo C. Please help me out.

Comment: I think you won't be available to work from user-mode with COM directly as it was in <bios.h>. If you want to use old connection, you should continue using 16-bit compiler and run your app in some dos emulator, i.e. dosbox. It will forward physical COM to the bios.h interfaces.

Comment: I could not understand completely what you meant to say? Can I run my .exe file of my program which has been developed in Mingw in DosBox? If yes how?

Comment: In your question you told about <bios.h>. Looks like this file was used in dos environment to communicate with COM port. This way of communicating on modern windows now isn't available. I assume you want the compile exe to be run in windows environment. In this case you should use another API. i.e. google for "CreateFile COM1"

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Please take a look here:

- [RS-232 for Linux and Windows](http://www.teuniz.net/RS-232/) <sup>1)</sup>
- [Windows Serial Port Programming](https://web.archive.org/web/20180127160838/http://bd.eduweb.hhs.nl/micprg/pdf/serial-win.pdf) <sup>2)</sup>
- [Using the Serial Ports in Visual C++](http://members.ee.net/brey/Serial.pdf) <sup>3)</sup>
- [Serial Communication in Windows](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2682/Serial-Communication-in-Windows)

<sup>1)</sup> *You can use this with Windows (incl. MinGW) as well as Linux. Alternative you can only use the code as an example.*

<sup>2)</sup> *Step-by-step tutorial how to use serial ports on windows*

<sup>3)</sup> *You can use this literally on MinGW*

Here's some very, very simple code (without any error handling or settings):

```
#include <windows.h>

/* ... */


// Open serial port
HANDLE serialHandle;

serialHandle = CreateFile("\\\\.\\COM1", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);

// Do some basic settings
DCB serialParams = { 0 };
serialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(serialParams);

GetCommState(serialHandle, &serialParams);
serialParams.BaudRate = baudrate;
serialParams.ByteSize = byteSize;
serialParams.StopBits = stopBits;
serialParams.Parity = parity;
SetCommState(serialHandle, &serialParams);

// Set timeouts
COMMTIMEOUTS timeout = { 0 };
timeout.ReadIntervalTimeout = 50;
timeout.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
timeout.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 50;
timeout.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
timeout.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;

SetCommTimeouts(serialHandle, &timeout);
```

Now you can use `WriteFile()` / `ReadFile()` to write / read bytes.
Don't forget to close your connection:

```
CloseHandle(serialHandle);
```

Comment: You tell you can also use it on Linux, but you '#include <windows.h>'? I'm unsure if it will/won't work on Linux/OSX.

Comment: No, you can use the information / code from the link on both systems. The code from my answer is Windows only.

Comment: The second link is dead but another copy (going off of file name here) is at http://bd.eduweb.hhs.nl/micprg/pdf/serial-win.pdf

Comment: second link is dead, any alternative please?

Answer (score 3):

For the answer above, the default serial port is

```
        serialParams.BaudRate = 9600;
        serialParams.ByteSize = 8;
        serialParams.StopBits = TWOSTOPBITS;
        serialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you can just use `boost::asio::serial_port`!