# Read serialport data in under 2ms in C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, serial-communication

I need to receive 3 characters every 2 milliseconds in a loop. I am using SerialPort.Read() but it takes 5 to 6 miliseconds to read incoming data. Is there possible way to do it? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it looping as fast as possible? If so then it's likely the serial connection that's too slow, and not your code.

Comment: SerialPort.Read() alone takes 5 to 6 ms and it doesn't even start to process incoming data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to call the serial port in C++, https://stackoverflow.com/a/15795522/67566

Then you can call that from C#, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235281.aspx

I expect this will be faster, but you will have a slow down in getting the data from C++ -> C#, and your window of 2-3 ms is very tiny.

You can get the data in that time, I expect, from C++, but you may need to buffer it, so I would put a timestamp with each piece of data, and when you call it from C# you may need to return more than one piece, and then process them.

In C++ DLL you will want to have a separate thread for reading from the serial port.

You will want to use the `thread` class, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh920601.aspx and detach it after creation.

And finally you will want to use a thread safe queue, so you can look at these two links and pick which one you like better:

https://juanchopanzacpp.wordpress.com/2013/02/26/concurrent-queue-c11/

[C++11 thread-safe queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278343/c11-thread-safe-queue)