# communication from pc to fpga with RS232

Tags: c++

we are creating a Qt application for controlling a robotic arm that has 6 motors and need to communicate from the application in PC with an FPGA board. We need to transmit commands in the form of 8 bits to each stepper motor. First 6 bits are for the motor number and last 2 bits consists of Forward(1) and backward(0) commands.
Later on, we will receive response from FPGA board regarding collision information in a form of 6 float values and immediately RS232 transmits this response back to server in order to display the position of collision part on robotic arm and if response is null nothing should be happened. Can anyone help me with the code in c++.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15794422/serial-port-rs-232-connection-in-c)

Comment: Do you have some code to show us ?