# Wemos D1 Mini (ESP8266) control with USB

Tags: c++

I have a Wemos D1 Mini (ESP8266), flashed with WLED and I want to create an application like .exe and have control on turning it on/off and choose colors. Does anyone have any idea how I can do without to connect on wifi and just do everything via USB?

Answer (score 1):

To control the WLED firmware over USB, you would use the firmware's [ability to be controlled over a serial connection](https://kno.wled.ge/interfaces/serial/). It looks like you would open the virtual serial port that appears when you plug in the device, at a speed of 115200, and then you take [the same JSON that you would `POST` to `/json/state`](https://kno.wled.ge/interfaces/json-api/) for controlling it over WiFi, and instead send it over the serial connection, and get your responses back over the serial connection.

You could also implement the [TPM2](https://gist.github.com/jblang/89e24e2655be6c463c56) protocol, or the [Adalight protocol](https://gist.github.com/baaldfg/557a708b322a9157c33cd3695c8b1154#file-ambilight-ino-L146-L158) (which doesn't really seem to be documented except in code), as those are also supposed to be supported.

If you want to do all this in C++ on Windows, you might start by reading the (very old) [Windows tutorials for Win32 API serial port programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ff802693(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). If you only want to target Win10 or newer, you could [learn C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/) and then use the [new WinRT serial APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.serialcommunication.serialdevice?view=winrt-22621). Or you could consult the answers to [this question about serial programming on Windows](https://%20https://stackoverflow.com/q/15794422).